# How to speed up matrix functions such as expm function in scipy/numpy?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm using `scipy` and `numpy` to calculate exponentiation of a 6*6 matrix for many times.

Compared to Matlab, it's about 10 times slower.

The function I'm using is `scipy.linalg.expm`, I have also tried deprecated methods `scipy.linalg.expm2` and `scipy.linalg.expm3`, and those are only two times faster than `expm`. My question is:

1. What's wrong with `expm2` and `expm3` as they are faster than `expm`?
2. I'm using wheel package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, and I found https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl-and-intel-fortran-on-windows. Is the wheel package compiled with MKL. If not, I think I can optimize and numpy, scipy by compile it by myself with MKL?
3. Any other ways to optimize the performance?

Comment: this performance is highly dependent on how NumPy or SciPy were compiled. Did you use the MKL-compiled versions in your comparisons? Such versions should be faster...

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have found answer for question 1 and 2 by myself
1. It seems expm2 and expm3 returns array rather than matrix. But they are about 2 times faster than expm

2. Well, after a whole day trying to compile scipy by MKL, I succeed. It's really hard to build the scipy, especially when I'm using windows, x64 and python3. It turned out to be a waste of time. It's not even a bit faster than the whl package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ .

Hoping someone give answer to question 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is relatively small, so maybe the numerical part is not the bottleneck. You should use a profiler to make sure that the limitation is in the exponentiation.
You can also take a look at the [source code of these implementations](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py#L212) and write an equivalent function with less conditionals and checking.